# What Python unittest command to run here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

Here's my project structure:

```
├── compute_completeness_service
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── integration
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── test__init__.py
│   │   └── unit
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── __pycache__
│   │       └── test_utils.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── __pycache__
├── data_quality
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   └── tests
│       └── unit
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── __pycache__
│           └── test_helpers.py
```

I can run these commands from `compute_completeness_service` and `data_quality`'s root directory:

```bash
python3 -m unittest discover -v -s ./compute_completeness_service/tests  -p "test_*.py"
python3 -m unittest discover -v -s ./data_quality/tests  -p "test_*.py"
```

but is there one command to run both of them? Because when I run this command, I get no tests:

```bash
python3 -m unittest discover -v -t .  -p "test_*.py" 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

TIA!

Comment: Your `tests` directories seem not to have an `__init.py__` - they may not be found during the test discovery.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MrBean Bremen's comment, I realized that I forgot to add `__init__.py` to the `tests` directories

Once added the test discovery worked as expected.